# Search in Content and skip html elements in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to search in content and I don't want to get fault result.
assume users search 'br' I don't want to see in output results that have <br> or <P> and other html elements

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you must strip the tags before you search. However, that would mean not being able to query the database directly. Rather, you'd have to pull all the objects first, and then query the collection in memory.

If you're going to be doing a lot of this or have large collections of objects (where pulling all of them for the initial query would be a performance drag), then you should look into a true search solution. I've been working with [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), which seems to be just about the best out there in my opinion. It's easy to set up, easy to use, and has third-party .NET integration through the nuget package, [NEST](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/).

With a true search solution, you can index your content fields, stripped of HTML, and then run your queries on the index instead of directly on your database. You'll also get powerful advanced features such as faceting, which would be difficult or impossible to do directly with Entity Framework.

Alternatively, if you can't go full board on the search and it's unacceptable to query everything up front (which really it pretty much *always* is), then your only other option is to create another companion field for each HTML content property, and always save a HTML-stripped copy of the text there. Then, use that field for your search queries.